# How do make install and make modules_install affect the existing kernel installed?

Tags: kernel, drivers, kernel-modules, initramfs

I installed Ubuntu 23.04 from a live USB, then obtained the source for Linux 6.5.5 and built a new kernel with some settings changed (mainly for some RT kernel experiments). I did `make install` but am now realizing I did not do `make modules_install`. It does not boot, dropping me to the initramfs shell, but doesn't recognize my USB keyboard.

My hunch of course is that not running `make modules_install` means I'm now missing all my drivers.

It's no big deal to reinstall and start this process over, and that's probably for the best since I'm unsure how to undo what I've done. But in order to not make the same mistakes I'm wondering if there's more to know about the mechanics of `make install` and `modules_install`. Does the new kernel refuse to use the old modules, or were they removed entirely? How do these methods relate to other kernel updating methods? Will this way result in me having two kernels to choose from in GRUB?